# OnCompleteListener Triggers After Return Statement

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm, firebase-authentication

I'm want to use firebase authentication in MVVM pattern and I'm messing around with ViewModels and LiveData to try and understand how this works.

I'm struggling to to understand why the following happens:

In my **repository** I attempt to login with email & password and simply return a **String** depending on result (I will eventually change this to be a user object)

```
        fun loginUser (email: String, password: String): String {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener{ authTask ->
            if (authTask.isSuccessful) {
                randomString = "Signed in!!"

            } else randomString = "Sign in failed!"  // 2. This happens after randomString is returned
        }
        return randomString // 1. Returns this first, so returning default value
    }
```

So I expected this to return either "Signed in!!" or "Sign in failed!" but the randomString is the default value and updated *after* it is returned..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` is asynchronous and returns a Task object immediately.  When you add a listener to it, that callback will be invoked some time later, after the operation completes.  Your `return` statement is actually returning the initial value of `randomString` before the result of the sign-in is available.

What you should do instead, if you are using Android Jetpack components, is return your own LiveData implementation that emits the result of the sign-in whenever it's complete.  The caller can observe that LiveData with their own callback to find out when it's done.

Comment: Thank you Doug - I'm honoured (I've only recently been watching you on youtube!)..

However, I have:
a Fragment, which observes a LiveData object in ViewModel and now I need 
a ViewModel to observe LiveData in Repository..

With the latter, I can't set a LifeCycleOwner as I would in the Fragment (and I thought doing so was an issue!?

Comment: Sure, use a ViewModel if you want.  LiveData doesn't require the use of a ViewModel, but it's a common pattern in Android MVVM to do so.

Comment: My post was moderated (hopefully this comment is ok!), but for completeness, I have updated my question here with solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874102/how-to-return-livedata-from-repository